# Unable to get from $_GET

Tags: php

I am unable to get the id from the `index.php` to the `profile.php`. I have tried some solutions from Stackoverflow but none seems to work

index.php:

```
$id = getfield('id'); //getfield is a function that pulls out the fields

<a class="profile" href="profile.php?=<?php echo $id.' ">'.ucfirst ($firstname);?></a>
```

profile.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    echo $id;
}
else
{
    echo 'cant get id';
}
```

The output is `can't get id`. 
I need the id to be echoed back to me.
I do not know what I am doing wrong here if some one could kindly guide me towards the right track it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Jake in index.php where do you declare/define the variable $id ?

Comment: hold on let me edit it

Comment: your href should end up looking like `profile.php?id=ID_HERE` your currently not setting the id to anything

Comment: this is how my browser url looks like
`/profile.php?=2`

Comment: look at my answer. You're not setting the `id` variable you just have a random `=2` at the end of your url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not setting anything in your url look:

```
<a class="profile" href="profile.php?=<?php echo $id.' ">'.ucfirst ($firstname);?></a>
                                    ^
```

should be

```
<a class="profile" href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $id.' ">'.ucfirst ($firstname);?></a>
                                     ^
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer so others may find this if they need to

Comment: i was stuck at this for hours and i cant believe how simple this was 
if it wasn't for you i would have never got it right

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding! you can upvote answers too! :)

Comment: i have just got 3 rep but i will mark it as correct as soon as i am ableto